# Load an AnyObject array into UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have an data model is an AnyObject array that contains the following structure:

```
[NSDictionary with 3 key value pairs, 
 NSDictionary with 3 key value pairs,  
 String, 
 String]
```

I would like to load this object into a UITableView, but I'm thinking that I should restructure it first. Also, I would like to populate the first two cells of my table view with the dictionary key values and the next two cells with the strings in the array.

Is this doable or should I consider restructuring my array?

Comment: Yes you can do it but for that you have to check its type by using `isKindOfClass` property in cellforrow method.

Comment: As @JigarTarsariya said, it's possible but I'm not sure it's the right thing to do. I wrote some answer below, but it hinges on some assumptions which may not hold. You might want to consider giving some more information about the array and the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to get rid of the array completely. At first I thought you meant every cell had this data, but it's the entire table. In that case I would pull the information out of the array as early as possible into a class. I'm assuming it is in that form because it comes from JSON or some such. If not, don't use it at all.

For example (obligatory car example):

**JSON**

```
"Honda Accord" : [
    "performance" : { 
        "0-60" : 7.6,
        "topSpeed" : 130,
        "1/4mile" : 15
    },
    "dimensions" : {
        "length" : 4.88,
        "weight" : 1577, 
        "wheelBase" : 2.4
    }
    "Model" : "Accord LX",
    "Code" : "Acd445"
}
```

This would be translated into a class to be accessed from you TableVC

**Class Car**

```
class Car {
    var zeroToSixty : Float
    var Code : String
}
```

Finally, in your TableVC, you would populate each cell based on the row number. A simple scenario would use the same cell type. A more complex one would require you to create different nibs for each cell but that's out of scope for this question.

Comment: Thanks for the information! So I think I may have gotten a little too fancy when parsing the json response. I need to rethink it a bit, but this definitely helps. Thanks!